# Array merge recursive static random

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**Update :** I've write my functions, and it works.

**My Own Answer**

```
<?php
function array_merge_recursive_random_static($first_array, $second_array, $key='')
{
    $merged_array = array_merge_recursive($first_array, $second_array);
    $arrays = &$merged_array;
    mt_srand(strlen($key)); 
    for ($i = count($arrays) - 1; $i > 0; $i--)
    { 
        $j = @mt_rand(0, $i); 
        $tmp = $arrays[$i]; 
        $arrays[$i] = $arrays[$j]; 
        $arrays[$j] = $tmp; 
    }
    return $arrays;
}
?>
```

**My Own Question :**

I have two arrays like this:

```
$array2 = array(
          0 => array('id' => 'dada', 'title' => 'this dada', 'desc' => 'dadaeating'),
          1 => array('id' => 'caca', 'title' => 'this caca', 'desc'=> 'caca eating') 
);

$array2 = array(
          0 => array('id' => 'baba', 'title' => 'this baba', 'desc' => 'baba eating'),
          1 => array('id' => 'memo', 'title' => 'this memo', 'desc'=> 'memo eating') 
);
```

I want merge $array1 and $array2 and make it static random unique, so I want my result like this :

```
$arrays = array(
          0 => array('id' => 'caca', 'title' => 'this caca', 'desc' => 'cacaeating'),
          2 => array('id' => 'memo', 'title' => 'this memo', 'desc'=> 'memo eating'),
          3 => array('id' => 'dada', 'title' => 'this dada', 'desc'=> 'dada eating'),
          4 => array('id' => 'baba', 'title' => 'this baba', 'desc'=> 'baba eating')
);
```

Everytime I reload page, output result always like result above.

Comment: static random unique... uh what?

Comment: I've found my answer :) yeah static random its useful for SEO, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just merge the arrays, then shuffle the resulting array.

```
$rand = array_merge($array1, $array2);
shuffle($rand);
```

$rand now contains the final version.